# Meaning of the command interval(inn,idum)?

Tags: fortran

Having a foundation as a theoretical physicist, I am not a programmer, but I need to pursue a lecture.

I need for a simulation of a quartic matrix model. The problem I encounter is that I have the solution to the program (from my teacher), but I need to decorate it.

When I insert the command `interval(medium,inn)` to define my lambda, I haven't any output, so what can I do?

```
real x0
pi=dacos(-1.0d0)
 idum=-148175
 x0=0.0d0
 idum=idum-2*int(secnds(x0))
 r=ran2(idum)

 inn=1.0d0
 do i=1,N
 lambda(i)=interval(idum,inn)
 enddo
 write(*,*) i,lambda
```

The code I have found is like that, where `idum` is defined as in integer and `interval` as double precision.

Reading the error, I think my compilation didn't recognize the notation `interval`:

```
C:\Users\CCM\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSSP1fD.o: In function `quartic_matrix_model':
C:/Users/CCM/Desktop/lattice field/Quartic_matrix_model.f:24: undefined reference to `_interval_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `interval(idum,inn)` references a function called `interval`: you need to define that function, or tell your linker where to find it.  Please give more details on your code so we can work out better which it is.

Comment: oh yes yess, i missed the code in the teacher code solution written as :
 
         function interval(idum,inn)
         implicit none
         double precision interval,inn,ran2
         integer idum
         interval=ran2(idum)
         interval=interval+interval-1.0d0
         interval=interval*inn
         return
         end

Comment: but iam always don't know what a function like that do ! 
and my goal is to draw the graphic of a function pho(lambda), but i didn't kniw how i can define them ! 
the function is number (5.3) "first-line" page 170, tha graphic page 176and the entire code is page 268 but he didn't contain any form of lambda who i search to draw.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02567.pdf

(sorry i can't add pictures here i think..)